# dateFormat('date','yyymmdd') ; use of 3y's is it correct?

Tags: coldfusion, sybase

I have a simple Search page, which searches for Contract-Site-inspection's from an Sybase database.
It has 3 form field variables:-

```
<form name="inspections" action="" method ="post">
  <!---a list of Sites where the Inspections occured --->
    <select name="selectSitesList" id="selectSitesList" multiple >                                                             
     <option value=""></option>
    </select>
   <input name="startDate" id="startDate" value="">  
   <input name="endDate" id="endDate" value="">     
    </form>
```

When startDate is given in the Search box, no results are selected by the query.(Ex:-01/01/2001) .But when NO startDate is provided in the search box (i.e StartDate is NULL or empty),all possible results show up.
The Sybase Select query is as follows:-

```
 SELECT   ins.Inspection_ID
                , ins.SiteLoc_ID
    , sl.SiteLoc_Name
    , ins.Inspected_By
    , ins.Inspection_Reason
    , ins.Inspection_Comments
    , ins.Inspection_Date 
        From INSPECTIONS ins
                        , SITELOCATION sl
        Where ins.SiteLoc_ID = sl.SiteLoc_ID 
        <cfif IsDefined ("form.selectSitesList") AND rtrim(ltrim(form.selectSitesList)) NEQ "">
            And ins.SiteLoc_ID in (#listqualify(form.selectSitesList,"'")#)
        </cfif>
        <cfif (IsDefined ("form.startDate") AND rtrim(ltrim(form.startDate)) NEQ "") and (IsDefined ("form.endDate") AND rtrim(ltrim(form.endDate)) NEQ "") >
            And CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ins.Inspection_Date, 112) Between '#DateFormat(form.startDate, 'yyymmdd')#' and '#DateFormat(form.endDate, 'yyymmdd')#'
        <cfelseif IsDefined ("form.startDate") AND rtrim(ltrim(form.startDate)) NEQ "">
            And CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ins.Inspection_Date, 112) = '#DateFormat(form.startDate, 'yyymmdd')#'
        </cfif>
        Order By sl.SiteLoc_Name
                              , ins.Inspection_Date
```

I was wondering if the #DateFormat(form.startDate, 'yymmdd')#  {2 y's} is correct instead of #DateFormat(form.startDate, 'yyymmdd')# {3 y's} 
Using CF-8.
 Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

Is the value that the CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ins.Inspection_Date, 112) construct producing something that can be sensibly compared to a value that '#DateFormat(form.startDate, 'yyymmdd')#' ?  "yyy" seems like a strange year mask to use (compared to the more common "yyyy" or "yy", I mean).

It seems odd to me that you are converting  the date cols in the DB to strings and converting your form fields to string sto compare them, rather than converting your form fields to dates and comparing them that way.

Also, whatever the underlying situation is here, you should be using CFQUERYPARAM to parameterise your dynamic values rather than hard-codingthemin your SQL string.

Comment: yes the Database-Date and the form field-dates are being converted to strings , and then being compared. Its a bit old fashioned (legacy code).

Comment: "yyy" is this even Legal? i thought only yyyy or yy is legal?anyhow when CONVERT 112 is used, then one should use "yyyy" right?

Comment: Well I presume so.  At the end of the day the value on the LHS of an expression needs to correspond to the values(s) on the RHS.  So if the CONVERT() call outputs yyyymmdd, then you need to use the same format for your formatting of your form variables, otherwise you're comparing oranges with orangutans

Comment: comparing oranges with orangutans ...lol nice laugh for lunch

Comment: Oh, come on!  Do some of your own investigation!  What does dateformat('date','yyymmdd') output?  What does CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ins.Inspection_Date, 112) output?  Is there any way that the output from the former can be sensibly used as a way of measuring two values between which the latter must lie?  Have you *read the docs* for dateFormat(), so that you understand how it works, and accordingly perhaps draw our own conclusions?  

Also (big hint): have you even read the other response here, just below this one?

Comment: Thanks Adam for the reply. I did investigate it and found that whats being done in the Legacy code is  "comparing oranges with orangutans".

Comment: You are absolutely right about it,  The Docs mention yyyymmdd or yymmdd but not yyymmdd.Hnece just wanted an confirmation from another person vis a vis yyymmdd. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try  #DateFormat(form.startDate, 'yyyymmdd')# ?

Answer (score 1):

If you must use strings, then the formats must match as Adam said. However, I would also suggest using datetime objects instead. As using the `convert` function that way may prevent the database from properly utilizing indexes. (Not to mention there is always the possibility for unexpected results when relying on implicit conversion. Though less so with `yyyymmdd` format)

I typically use the query below for date range comparisons. It retrieves all records within a specific *date* range, without having to worry about the time portion. Note, the sql types for Sybase may be slightly different.

```
<cfset form.startDate = "01/01/2001">
<cfset form.endDate   = "01/31/2001">
...
<!--- cf_sql_date ensures any time portion is truncated --->
AND ins.Inspection_Date >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
AND ins.Inspection_Date < <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1, form.endDate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
```

.. The result is equivalent to your `BETWEEN` statement ie Find all records *dated* between January 1st and 31st of 2001

```
...
AND ins.Inspection_Date >= January 1, 2001 12:00 AM
AND ins.Inspection_Date < February 1, 2001 12:00 AM
```

Comment: thanks but on related note is using 3ys in dateformat('date','yyymmdd') correct?

Comment: It is technically *allowed*. But it may be making things more confusing. You seem to be comparing a `yyyymmdd` string to a `yymmdd` formatted string, which does not make much sense. That is why I recommended using date objects instead. So you do not have to worry about formatting.